# Enabling systemd support in WSL caused an resource invalid error

Tags: systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I upgraded my OS to Windows 11 in hopes of getting Systemd support in my WSL2 Ubuntu distro. But after I enabled the Systemd support using the documentation on [Microsoft Developer blogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/), I'm receiving the following error when I start Docker Desktop application:

```
RemoteApp

The Connection information for this resource is invalid.
```

[image: The screenshot of error that I faced.]

I tried to search on the web and found a similar issue on [WSL's GitHub Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8888).  I've tried all the ways mentioned on that issue, but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

My WSL version is 1.0.3.0 and the Docker Desktop version is 20.10.21.

Comment: Does the problem just occur when starting Docker Desktop?  Or does it also occur when just starting Ubuntu with no Docker Desktop running?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds When I start Docker Desktop then only this problem occurs

Comment: Hmmm.  The latest Docker Desktop is `4.15.0 (93002)` and you mentioned `20.10.21`.  That doesn't sound quite right.  Where are you getting that version from?  You can see the installed Docker Desktop version in the Docker Desktop *Settings -> Software updates*.  I'm still thinking about what the cause could be, but definitely want to confirm the version numbers as well.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yeah, you are right my docker desktop version is `4.15.0` . I think by I've seen some other version related to something else. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem with ***systemd*** is finally solved. I just uninstalled the wsl from the control panel and again reinstall the wsl program.
I think the issue was with ***wsl*** that was installed before the reinstallation.